# Kendo MVC - Need DatePicker in a Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datepicker

I have the following grid with a date picker:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ScheduleViewModel>()
        .Name("ScheduleGrid")
        .AutoBind(true)
        -
        )
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(s => s.Name).Title("Schedule").Filterable(true).Width(150).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: left" });
            columns.Bound(s => s.StartTime).Width(100).Title("Start Time").ClientTemplate((
              @Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
               .Name("StartTimePicker")
               .Value("#=StartTime#")
               //.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
               .ToClientTemplate()).ToHtmlString());
            columns.Bound(s => s.Enabled).Width(100).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #=Enabled ? checked='checked' : '' # class='sda-checkbox' />").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text-center" });
            columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Save").Click("saveSchedules")).Width(80).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "text-center" });
        })
```

However, the date picker doesn't display correctly. Instead it is just a text box. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

EDIT *(and I also switched to use a Time Picker instead of a Date Picker)*:

I did as @FrozenButcher suggested, but this still doesn't work. This is what happens now:

Bring up page and you get this, which does not LOOK like a Time Picker, but is. No clock icon, and you can't see the value:

[image]

Click in the box and you get this:

[image]

Obviously you can now see the time, but no clock icon.

Finally, click in the Time Picker on the second line and you get this:

[image]

Any help in resolving this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure unique ids for your inputs, wrapper for datepicker is defined through the name property.

change it to a dynamic name `.Name("StartTimePicker"+ lineNumber)`

Comment: Thanks. In the EDIT above I describe what happens now. Adding a unique name changed this for the better, but I still have issues.